# How to fix my navigation to work in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, navigation

I'm having an issue with my navigation, the first list item appears to have a huge gap on the right.

I have a list of links inside an UL each have their own class so I could set a background icon to them. The first link has a background to give it the rounded effect.

I used relative to push to left so it would have that rounded effect for the hover and active states on the homepage and hover for when i'm on other pages.

Now it all works fine in new browsers apart from IE7 and probably older versions.

I've put it on JSFiddle to make it easier to view.

http://jsfiddle.net/datastream/Gta3h/2/

and http://eminemforum.net/navtest/nav2.html

Thanks

Comment: Margins and paddings won't apply to a A element that is not set to `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Pekka: The point is moot now (I think I've solved the problem), but for future reference: if you go to the ["full screen version"](http://jsfiddle.net/datastream/Gta3h/2/embedded/result/), you can then use the Compatibility View button to see it in IE7 mode easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gta3h/5/show/light/) ([edit](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gta3h/5/))

- I got rid of `<div id="navHold">`.
- I removed `right: 40px` from `#topNav2 .home-icon`.
- I changed the width of `#Navigation-Holder` from `750px` to `830px` to make it appear the same width it was before I changed anything.

I've tested that this looks consistent in: IE7, IE8, Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: your live demo works. When i tried doing what you said the first link wouldnt push to left and there is a just a gap. I don't know why, I even copied it directly from the code you edited

Comment: Looking at your new link: http://eminemforum.net/navtest/ - that still seems to have `<div id="navHold">`. Is that the old code, or my code, on that link?

Comment: @thirtdot Sorry for the confusion the right was still there on the active-link class. It works now, thanks for the help!